# Php artisan serve command

Tags: php, artisan-serve

i run command php artisan serve but that was the results:
php artisan serve

INFO  Server running on [http://127.0.0.1:8000].

Press Ctrl+C to stop the server

This continued for a few seconds and then stopped automatically. What is wrong here?

I hope to get an answer to that

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a look at this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to be able to [post a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

We are not sure what really, problem going on. If your other artisan command run successfully, then it sure that laravel project setup successfully.

Try to run the laravel project on the different  port, may be default port is busy.

```
php artisan serve --port 2000
```

Also try other port like 1000,3000,8080 etc.
If you get any error message tell us, so that we can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed, the server became operational when I used the port
  1000, but this error occurred. Is it because the project is empty?                                                            WARN  PHP Warning: Unknown: Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0.

Comment: Make sure your file & directory permission is correct , also sure all laravel the required file available in the project directory. And use the command to get proper error in laravel php artisan serve --verbose or php artisan serve --debug .Try it, we  are sure it will worked.